# Suppose the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have a joint pdf $f(x,y)=6y$, $0<y<x<1$

Tags: covariance

Find $Cov(X,Y)$

My work:

I found that $E(X) = .75$ and $E(Y)=.50$
$E(XY) = \int_0^1{\int_0^1} xyf(x,y) dydx  = {\int_0^1}\int_0^16xy^2 dy dx = \int_0^1 2x dx = 1$

so $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)\cdot E(Y) = 1 - .75\cdot.5= \frac58$

But my book says that the correct answer is $\cfrac{1}{40}$

Where did I go wrong? I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Your joint pdf is $f(x,y)=6y$ when $0<y<x<1$. Presumably for $y > x$, $f(x,y) = 0$, so $\int_0^1 yf(x,y)dy = \int_0^x yf(x,y) dy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EXY=\int_0^{1}\int_0^{x} xy (6y)dydx$. This evaluates to $\frac  2 5$ so $cov(X,Y)=\frac  2 5-(0.75)(0.5)=0.025$

Comment: I see so the first integral is from 0 to x because y is limited by x. But the second integral is from 0 to 1 because there is no constraint on x (besides 0 to 1) because x is always greater then y. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: @ Yes, It is correct. @BadwaterBarry

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$$
E(XY) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 6xy^2 \mathbb{1}_{0 < y<x<1}dx dy 
= \int_0^1 \int_y^1 6xy^2dx dy= \frac{2}{5}
$$